# GWT - server side - how to add external lib right to war file with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, servlets

I have tried to add external jar to eclipse project and it works in "Run as -> GWT application" mode only. But when I deploy it to Tomcat the external jar is missing in the exported WAR file :( Please tell me how can I add an external lib to gwt project to have it be added automatically to exported war file (servlets use it)?

Any useful comments are appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the file to the war/WEB-INF/lib folder. You can simply drag the file to that folder. Then add the file your build path by right clicking on the project -> properties -> build path -> libraries tab.

Comment: Emm... Should I do this manually? Or there is a eclipse option for this?

Comment: Yep, manually copy the jar file there (and add it to the java build path of course).

Comment: You mean I should add it manually to the eclipse project war/WEB-INF/lib folder and then deploy but now with eclipse?

Comment: You can deploy using the Google eclipse plugin or through the command line, the whole war folder will be included in the war file, including the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: OK, but what if I add the lib to "user libs" and then add it to my gwt project? Will it make the same effect?

Comment: Yep that works but just make sure that the actual location of the file is in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @user592704 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1035/discussion-between-abdullah-jibaly-and-user592704)

Comment: It's OK I got it :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1/ Click Project -> Properties -> Project Facets :: Convert to faceted form;

2/ Check Dynamic Web Module;

3/ Add *.jar to /war/WEB-INF/lib, it automatically will be referenced by eclipse into "Web App Libraries" and be exported with *.war

Comment: Thank you it is quite interesting :) But is there a facets option if there is only eclipse and gwt installed? I ask because I didn't see the option in my current eclipse. Should I install some additional plugins for this?

Comment: Yes, find at Eclipse Software Repository download.eclipse.org/releases/{release} this plugins: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools, Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools, Eclipse Web Developer Tools, Eclipse Faceted Project Framework. Then you can create New -> Dymanic Web Project. It's already faceted